# How to get status code from response API without Http Get using KlaviyoClient?

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, http-status-codes

I am using a third party API and want to get the status code response from this.
It doesn't use the usual http.get(request, header) format.

How would we get the status code from this?
This is the link I referenced

```
// Get the timeline for all events on a profile.
KlaviyoClient.profiles.getProfileMetricsTimeline({
    profileId: 'myProfileId',
    since: 1606262400,
    count: 50,
    sort: 'asc'
});
```

I'm using typescript and I tried to do

```
const response = await KlaviyoClient.profiles.getProfileMetricsTimeline({
    profileId: 'myProfileId',
    since: 1606262400,
    count: 50,
    sort: 'asc'
});
```

But this doesn't return the status code. What do we need to do?
Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest you use a more popular HTTP client like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KlaviyoClient` library [abstracts the handling of success](https://github.com/klaviyo/node-klaviyo/blob/1.1.0/lib/request.js#L99-L112) and error responses.

`statusCode` is only available on `Error` objects thrown from requests through the client library.

These errors can be handled as follow

```js
let response;
try {
   response = await KlaviyoClient.profiles.getProfileMetricsTimeline({
    profileId: 'myProfileId',
    since: 1606262400,
    count: 50,
    sort: 'asc'
   });
} catch (e) {
   console.error(e.statusCode);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and sample! Yes surprisingly there is no status for success, but good to at least know we can get the error status code

Comment: For the successful responses you can assume a `200` or `202`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [here](https://github.com/klaviyo/node-klaviyo/blob/260f89a38bd97d7b2e8aaeacdfe55e1581c6cd48/lib/profiles.js), if error occurs, you will get a `KlaviyoError`, that as you can see from [here](https://github.com/klaviyo/node-klaviyo/blob/260f89a38bd97d7b2e8aaeacdfe55e1581c6cd48/lib/errors.js#L3), contains the status code (inside `KlaviyoApiError`)